# Why is Valgrind giving me errors in the wrong place?

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, valgrind

I'm fixing three bugs in the following C program. The first two are given and guaranteed to be correct. The third one is one I will write at the end and is irrelevant to my issue. The last three are where the issues are at, each exhibit a bug.

Here is my program:

```
/* is correct*/
Node *create_list(int arr[], int size) {
  Node *n, *list= NULL;

  if (arr != NULL && size != 0)
    while (size-- > 0) {

      n= malloc(sizeof(*n));
      if (n == NULL)
        return NULL;  /* we just return NULL if memory allocation fails */
      else {
        n->value= arr[size];
        n->next= list;
        list= n;
      }
    }

  return list;
}

/* is correct*/
void list_to_string(Node *list, char result[]) {
  char temp[MAX_LEN + 1];

  strcpy(result, "");  /* clear out any existing contents */

  while (list != NULL) {
    sprintf(temp, "%d", list->value);

    if (strlen(result) + strlen(temp) + 1 < MAX_LEN) {
      strcat(result, temp);

      /* add a space if it's not the last element */
      if (list->next != NULL)
        strcat(result, " ");
    }

    list= list->next;
  }
}

/*****************************************************************************/
/*       functions below this have something wrong with them     */
/*****************************************************************************/

/* this function's parameter is a pointer to the head node of a list; it
 * should release all of the memory of the list, and set the head pointer
 * (meaning the pointer that its parameter points to) to NULL. (Empty for now).
 */
void clear(Node **list) {
}

/* should return the sum of the values in the even-numbered positions of a
 * list (the value in the second node, the fourth node, etc.), but has a bug
 * (the first node is considered to be position #1, in other words, the list
 * has no position zero)
 */
int sum_even(Node *list) {
  Node *ptr= list->next;
  int sum= 0;

  if (list != NULL){
    while (ptr != NULL) {
      sum += ptr->value;
      ptr= ptr->next->next;
    }  
  }

  return sum;
}

/* should remove the last element from a list, returning 1 upon success or 0
 * if start is NULL, but has a bug
 */
int remove_last(Node **start) {
  Node *prev= NULL, *travel;
  int result= 0;

  if (start != NULL) {

    result= 1;

    travel= *start;
    while (travel != NULL && travel->next != NULL) {
      prev= travel;
      travel= travel->next;
    }

    if (prev != NULL) {
      free(prev->next);
      prev->next= NULL;
    }

  }

  return result;
}

/* should remove the first element from a list, returning 1 upon success or
 * 0 if the list is empty or start is NULL, but has a bug
 */
int remove_first(Node **start) {
  Node **temp= NULL;
  int result= 0;

  if (start != NULL && *start != NULL) {

    result= 1;
    temp= start;
    *start= (*start)->next;
    free(temp);

  }

  return result;
}
```

My main test function:

```
int main(void) {
  int arr[]= {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};
  Node *list= NULL;
  char elements[MAX_LEN + 1];

  list= create_list(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));

  /* test sum_even() */
  assert(sum_even(list) == 120);

  /* test remove_last() */
  remove_last(&list);
  list_to_string(list, elements);
  assert(strcmp(elements, "10 20 30 40 50 60") == 0);

  printf("Score!\n");  /* both assertions passed */

  /* if your clear() function works, this program should not have any memory
     leaks, and list should be NULL afterwards */
  clear(&list);

  return 0;
}
```

I understand that 'clear()' is empty, but that's a function I will write at the end. What I'm confused about is when I run valgrind with:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --track-fds=yes my_program.x
```

I get this message:

```
==25457== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25457== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25457== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25457== Command: public1.x
==25457==
Score!
==25457==
==25457== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 3 open at exit.
==25457== Open file descriptor 2: /dev/pts/11
==25457==    <inherited from parent>
==25457==
==25457== Open file descriptor 1: /dev/pts/11
==25457==    <inherited from parent>
==25457==
==25457== Open file descriptor 0: /dev/pts/11
==25457==    <inherited from parent>
==25457==
==25457==
==25457== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25457==     in use at exit: 96 bytes in 6 blocks
==25457==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 1 frees, 112 bytes allocated
==25457==
==25457== 80 bytes in 5 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 2
==25457==    at 0x4C28A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==25457==    by 0x40077F: create_list (broken-lists.c:16)
==25457==    by 0x400698: main (public1.c:14)
==25457==
==25457== 96 (16 direct, 80 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==25457==    at 0x4C28A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==25457==    by 0x40077F: create_list (broken-lists.c:16)
==25457==    by 0x400698: main (public1.c:14)
==25457==
==25457== LEAK SUMMARY:
==25457==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==25457==    indirectly lost: 80 bytes in 5 blocks
==25457==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25457==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25457==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25457==
==25457== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25457== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Which clearly says that the function call to create_list() has an issue. Since I know for a fact that create_list() is correct and remove_last() has an issue, why is it telling me create_list() has an issue?

I'm trying to learn Valgrind at the moment so please excuse me if this question is obvious to some of you.

Comment: I don't think that's true. n is not lost but reassigned every time. There are no previous n's. It's just a tempory pointer that's being reused every time. Besides that is the fact that this function was not of my work. This whole program is part of an assignment and it's given that create_list has no bugs.

Comment: How exactly do you free the list? The function `clear()` is empty.

Comment: my I have egg on my face .. my apologies. I honed in on `list=n` .. but my assertion of "this code was given to me, therefore it is bug free" still stands. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. @B.Li you are correct, what I was complaining about is not a memory leak.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi It looks like he hasn't gotten to that yet, he's trying to fix other problems first.

Comment: I think what valgrind is telling you is that the lost memory was allocated in `create_list`, not that `create_list` is where it's being lost.

Comment: @Barmar Then why is OP wondering why the memory allocated in `create_list()` is still flaping in the breeze at teh end?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi Because he's misunderstanding valgrind's messages.

Comment: Yeah the idea is I don't understand why valgrind is telling me create_list has an issue, which is not possible. I'm obviously not interpreting the valgrind message right

Comment: heh well you're probably done listening to me, but I would guess that valgrind knows you're `malloc`ing memory in `create_list`, but you're never `free`ing it. As @deamentiaemundi mentioned your `clear` function is empty.. are you iterating through your `list` anywhere and `free`ing the memory you `malloc`ed in `create_list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create_list` calls `malloc` inside a loop. If the `malloc` inside the loop is ok the first N times but fails the N+1 time, you return `NULL` and thereby leak the memory from the first N mallocs. So this is clearly a bug in `create_list` which I would expect `valgrind` to report.

You need something like:

```
if (n == NULL)
{
    clear(&list);
    return NULL;  /* we just return NULL if memory allocation fails */
}
```

Besides that I'm not sure it makes sense to run `valgrind` before you have implemented a `clear` function. How should `valgrind` know that you intend to free the memory in a function that has not been written yet?

Comment: You're right. I should have implemented clear() first.

Comment: OK. But you also need to fix the bug in `create_list` :-)

Comment: I don't see what you're saying about create_list. Why would it leak the first N iteration? It would just stop making the linked list and exit.

Comment: @b.li yes, exactly. It will Just return NULL so you have no pointer to first malloced elements, i.e. a memory leak

Comment: ? I think I still would. It would just be a pointer pointing to NULL. That's not a memory leak.

Comment: What happen to the N elements held by list? They are leaked.... Assume the 3 first malloc Works them list holds the three. When number 4 malloc fails, you loose the elements held by list.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was.
It turns out clear() needed to be called before main exists or list will contain unfreed memory.
I didn't think this was the case at first because of the bugs in the three functions. The bugs in sum_even() and remove_last() does not apply to the specific list made in main(). So for this run, nothing was wrong.